# Accessing source code for Spring Annotations

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Where can I see the source code behind the `@Service` or `org.springframework.stereotype.Service` in the Spring framework?

Answer (score 1):

Annotations themselves do not carry implementation logic, just some simple attributes. The framework (Spring in our case) just checks for the existence of annotations (i.e instances of an annotation class like `Service`) on our classes and then acts accordingly. For example, if it sees a `Service` present, it will instantiate our class as a bean and manage that bean.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IDE, to check `@Service` implementation you can press `Ctrl` and click on this annotation. `org.springframework.stereotype.Service` interface will be opened in this case.

Comment: I know to access the interface, but what I need is to access the code used by this @service. In other words, where is the code that runs this annotation?

Comment: By using `@ComponentScan` Spring will understand where your components are stored. Spring will took package with your components and then inject them as beans. This logic is hidden under the hood of Spring Framework.

Answer (score 0):

For Example if you want to find the logic for @Autowired in Spring Boot.

Right Click on the pom.xml, Select Maven->Download Resources.

Now in the external libraries the @Autowired annotation is defined in the org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation package. The source file is typically named Autowired.java.

The logic for this annotation is found in the same folder.

Look into classes like AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor and DefaultListableBeanFactory. These classes are part of the Spring container and are involved in the process of detecting and injecting dependencies.